# Azure Pipelines - Prevent PR Update Trigger Upon PR Merge

Tags: python, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am struggling with this issue. I have an `azure-pipelines.yml` which is set to build a python artifact in three different ways- one upon merge to `master`(1.0.x), to `develop` (0.5.xrc) and otherwise just a dev artifact (0.3.x.dev0), x being the incremental number.

I understand that the build needs to increment upon a pull-request update, and it produces an artifact with version 0.3.x.dev0 which is expected. However upon merge, it triggers the build of the prod or rc version (1.0.x or 0.5.xrc), but then it also automatically runs another pipeline to build a dev artifact.

My question is, how do I remove the duplicate build upon merge to `develop` or `master`? This is presumably to do with a PR update trigger upon merge. I added the `autoCancel` functionality but that does not seem to have helped.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - master

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - master
  autoCancel: true

variables:

  initialVersion: '1.0.0'

  buildCounter: $[counter(variables['initialVersion'], 0)]

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    Python310:
      python.version: '3.10'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

# Increment the version based on prod release
- script: |
    set -e
    if [[ "$(Build.SourceBranch)" == "refs/heads/master" ]]; then
      echo "1.0.10" > VERSION.txt
    elif [[ "$(Build.SourceBranch)" == "refs/heads/develop" ]]; then
      echo "0.5.$(buildCounter)rc" > VERSION.txt
    else
      echo "0.3.$(buildCounter).dev0" > VERSION.txt
    fi
  displayName: 'Set Version based on Branch'

- script: |
    set -e
    version=$(cat VERSION.txt)
    echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$version"
  displayName: 'Update Build Number'


- script: |
    set -e
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    python -m unittest discover -v
    python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
  displayName: 'Install dependencies, run unit tests, build and create artifact'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build.zip"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build.zip'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    artifactName: 'artifact-name'
```

Comment: What kind of repo source you are using? (Github repo or Bitbucket repo or Azure Repo) Can you share the screenshot about the duplicate run?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am on the Azure DevOps platform itself.

Comment: I know that you are using the Azure DevOps Pipeline. But do you mean that you are also using Azure Repo?  If yes, you don't need to define the **pr:** field in the YAML file. Refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

Comment: Ah thanks @KevinLu-MSFT I had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the similar issue when using Bitbucket .

The cause of this issue could be that the WEBHOOKs of Repo Resource are mixed on Bitbucket.

You can refer to the following steps to re-create the Webhook and check if it can work.

Step1: Navigate to **Bitbucket repo setting -> Webhooks** and remove all **Repository hooks** related to Azure DevOps.

[image]

Step2: Navigate to **Azure Devops YAML Pipeline -> Triggers Option -> Trigger tab** . Click the restore option, it will automatically create new webhook in Bitbucket Webhook

[image]

If you are using Github Repo, you can also check the webhook in repo resource and recreate the webhook in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using branch policies to protect these branches and only push new changes to the `develop` and `master` using PR's, then I am assuming you do not actively need the CI trigger for this pipeline.

You get the duplicate runs because first it triggers a build for the PR, and once the PR gets merged to `develop` / `master`, it will hit the CI trigger defined in `trigger`.

**Suggestion #1**
So to stop the duplicate build upon merge, you could simply add `trigger: none`.
Like mentioned, that is assuming you are looking only to get new changes into `develop` and `master` branches using PR and build validation from PR.

**Suggestion #2**
If I am on the other hand assuming you are less restrictive towards the `develop` branch, meaning we do **not** protect it from direct pushes using branch policies, while we want PR's before we merge new code to `master`, then my setup would look like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
```

**Suggestion #3**
You can also add build validations using branch policies:
[image: build-validation-1]
[image: build-validation-2]

Maybe I misunderstood what you are actually looking for, but let me know!